# How to get facebook's friend email?

Tags: rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How to get facebook's friend email? Or their email hash?

Comment: What would you want the email hash for? For a gravatar? Don't you have the facebook image? For searching for users on e.g. api.stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

it is not possible. if you take a closer look at [the existing extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) , email for friends is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly (and also thankfully!) you are unable to do that.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ should show you all the things you have access to through the Graph API.  You can get their profile information - gender, friends, date of birth and all that, but the email is secured.

On http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions you can see the following:

> email     **not available**   Provides access to the user's primary email address in the email property. Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply both with Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

So it looks like it may have been once, but at the moment and for the foreseeable future, it's not possible to access it.

Comment: But what about email hashes? I see a lot of the web says you can get email hashes